# How to set maximum limit to monit alert trigger?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, monitoring, monit

I have monit setup on servers. I am sending out SNS on monit alerts as below.

```
check filesystem "root" with path /dev/xvda1
    if space usage > 80% for 10 cycles then exec "/bin/bash -c '/usr/local/bin/publishsns.sh DISK GT80 server1'" as uid root and gid root
```

I am getting overwhelmed by the messages when the disc space is greater then 80%. Last time I got around 200 messages that to in an hour.

Is there a way to disable monit after a while for a check?